# Aws::S3::S3Client constructor very slow

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm trying to use the AWS C++ SDK to generate a signed URL for S3, however the `Aws::S3::S3Client` constructor seems very slow. In the following example:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
 
int main() {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    printf("1\n");
    Aws::S3::S3Client client;
    printf("2\n");
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ example.cc -laws-cpp-sdk-core -laws-cpp-sdk-s3
```

there is long delay (at least 5 seconds) between `1` and `2`. What is causing this?

The library was built and installed with:

```
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
cd aws-sdk-cpp
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_ONLY="s3"
make
make install
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not running on AWS, set:

```
AWS_EC2_METADATA_DISABLED=true
```

to disable the metadata API which is what's causing the delay.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/1511 this issue explains the "bug" introduced in v1.8x and the workaround above

Answer (score 4):

Not C++, but C#. Your thread was the only one I could find with a title describing my problem. You "inspired" me to go through the `AWSOptions`'s properties.

My newest project is built on **.Net 6** and the **AWSSDK.S3** Nuget package.

Application startup was blazing fast, but first use / instance creation (through injection) took something like 8 to 10 seconds.

What did the trick for me was setting the `DefaultConfigurationMode` in `Program.cs`.

```
var awsOptions = builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
awsOptions.DefaultConfigurationMode = DefaultConfigurationMode.Standard;

[...]

builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Hero! This was an issue for me for days. Thank you.